# Firefox 3.6.8 doesn't work with an anchor, it rolls down to the page's bottom

Tags: html, firefox, hyperlink

There is an anchor in one of my websites.

http://www.autostitkok.hu/tozsde3.html#jelentkezes

Firefox 3.6.8 doesn't "stop" at the anchor if I use an anchored link, but rolls down to the bottom of the page.

If I click into the address bar of the browser, and hit enter, the browser jumps to the right place, but obviously this isn't the way it supposed to work...

I asked other users and they have the same experience with this link on this site, so the problem can't be my computer.

Other browsers work properly.

I tried Opera, Google Chrome, and IE8.

Thank you,
Gabor

Comment: I see that the tag in question is empty; would it help to add e.g. a `&nbsp;` into it?

Comment: Thank you, it didn't solve the problem, but Martey had the solution!
Thanks for trying,
Gabor

Answer (score 3):

Searching on Google suggests that [the name attribute is deprecated for links](http://derickrethans.nl/html-name-attribute-deprecated.html). You might want to try using the id attribute (`<a id="jelentkezes">`)instead.

If that does not work, I think looking into the [HTML validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.autostitkok.hu%2Ftozsde3.html) would a reasonable next step.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much! This is the solution!

Kind regards,
Gabor Holics

Comment: :-(((( I don't know what happened. Last time it was OK, now I tried again, and it didn't work second time.

Comment: Validation didn't give the answer either.